# get set method of lwc isn't producing desired result

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

/* HTML File */

```
<template>
    Value = {uppercaseItemName}
</template>
```

/* JS File */

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class GetSetLWC extends LightningElement {
    uppercaseItemName = 'abcd';
    
    get itemName() {
        console.log('Inside get');
        return this.uppercaseItemName;
    }
    
    set itemName(value){
        console.log('Inside set');
        this.uppercaseItemName = value.toUpperCase()
    }
}
```

I am trying to convert this text in to upper case using set method but it is throwing abcd only which is original text. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are not using the getter. Update the template to use `{itemName}` and it will work with the exception that the initial value for your private internal property, `uppercaseItemName`, will not be automatically set to be uppercase. The uppercase will only happen when setting `itemName`.

You would honestly be better off with something like:

```
/*HTML File*/
        <template>
            Value = {itemName}
        </template>
    
    /* JS File */
    import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
    
    export default class GetSetLWC extends LightningElement {
        _itemName = 'abcd';
    
        get itemName() {
            console.log('Inside get');
            return this._item Name?.toUpperCase();
        }
    
        set itemName(value){
            console.log('Inside set');
            this._itemName = value;
        }
    }
```

That way you always get an uppercase version of the value, regardless as to how it is first initialized. Note that I put _ on the front of the property name to signify that it is private - this is just a naming convention.